# Javascript onclick firing 4 times

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

The login form is supposed to show an alert if the password is wrong. However, it shows the alert 4 times.

The button with id:'loginbutton' triggers the function 'auth()' onclick.
It works okay for login and logout. But when I try with wrong username,password pairs the alert message  window.alert("Wrong username or password")  is shown four times once after another. Which means the onclick() event is being triggered four times for some reason.

Here the same Sign in button also works as the sign out button. I am using the function setLoginButton() to determine the current state of the user (logged in or not) and update the button text based on that.

HTML:

```
<body onload = "setLoginButton()">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lorem</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="auth(event)" id="loginbutton">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Javascript:

```
// Init datatables
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#content1').DataTable();
    $('#holdTable').hide();
} );


function setLoginButton() {
    token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('cicitoken');
    if (token == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 400) {
                window.sessionStorage.removeItem('cicitoken');
                buttonText = "Sign In";
                displayForm = "block";
            } 
            else {
                buttonText = "Sign Out";
                displayForm = "none";
            }
            document.getElementById("loginbutton").innerHTML = buttonText;
            document.getElementById("username").style.display = displayForm;
            document.getElementById("password").style.display = displayForm;
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/api-token-verify/", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"token": token}));
    }
}


//auth function to get token and use sessionstorage
auth = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('cicitoken');
    if ( token != null) {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem('cicitoken');
        location.reload()
    }
    else {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        jdata={username:document.getElementById("username").value,password:document.getElementById("password").value};
        xhttp.onerror = function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        xhttp.onabort = function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('cicitoken',response.token);
            }
            else {
                window.alert("Wrong username or password");
                setLoginButton();
            }
            setLoginButton();
        }

        xhttp.open("POST", "/api-token-auth/", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(jdata));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting type button and event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest will loop through their ready states.
So it starts at state 0, and it will go through each state until it reaches state 4, completed.

Since your alert is tied to the onreadystatechange event, that event will also get called 4 times:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('cicitoken',response.token);
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Wrong username or password");
        setLoginButton();
    }            
    setLoginButton();
}
```

Since the alert is tied to the condition: `if readyState !== 4`, it will show the alert for states 0, 1, 2 and 3.

The solution is to include the alert into the `if readyState === 4` block somewhere instead of having it outside it. You can then also bind the alert to the onerror event of the XMLHttpRequest to catch errors if the XMLHttpRequest fails before it reaches readyState 4.

This also implies that all the changing of styles you do in the other readystatechange handler also gets called way too many times instead of only when the result of the request is known.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the same issue, this is how I modified the code according to the answer by @Shilly:

```
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('cicitoken',response.token);
            setLoginButton();
        }
        else if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==400){
            window.alert("Wrong username or password");
            setLoginButton();
        }
    }
```